# I am looking for a complex sparse matrix EigenVector solver for GPGPU; preferably CUDA

Tags: eigensystem, eigenvalues, gpu, viennacl

So far the closest I've found is ViennaCL, which has a Lanczos implementation for Eigenvalues.

It is not clear that EigenVectors are produced by this library.

Does anyone here know whether ViennaCL solves for EigenVectors? And how to get them?

Or of any other sparse matrix EigenVector solver for GPGPU?

ETA:From what I have read, Lanczos is only an algorithm for converting from a general matrix to tridiagonal form. The QR algorithm (or other) is needed for extracting EigenValues/Vectors from the tridiagonal matrix.

Assuming I can upgrade the ViennaCL library to handle complex matricies, does anyone have a recommendation for a GPU based QR algorithm implementation?

Comment: How many eigenvectors do you need? All of them? Only a few? Do you need high accuracy or just good approximations?

Comment: Re the ETA: no, Lanczos **is** an algorithm for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors. It can be used as a tridiagonalization algorithm (if you make $n$ iterations, where $n$ is the size of the matrix), but its main purpose is stopping much earlier than that and computing eigenpairs from the tridiagonal matrix of smaller size that you obtain.

Comment: @KarlRupp , We only need the largest value/vector. Good approximations will probably do. We need the equivalent of Matlab EIGS on GPU.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni may I suggest that you correct the information on Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm

Comment: @JohnSmith That page has multiple issues, but it states clearly that "[t]he Lanczos algorithm is an iterative algorithm [...] to find the most useful eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a[...] linear system with a limited number of operations". Where did you read that it is an algorithm to convert a matrix to a tridiagonal form?

Comment: What about using power iterations instead of Lanczos if you only need the largest eigenvalue/eigenvector?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni "After the iteration, we get the \alpha_j and \beta_j which construct a tridiagonal matrix.... **Solve for eigenvalues and eigenvectors**
After the matrix T_{mm} is calculated, one can solve its eigenvalues \lambda_i^{(m)} and their corresponding eigenvectors u_i^{(m)} (for example, using the QR algorithm or Multiple Relatively Robust Representations (MRRR)). "

Comment: @KarlRupp Our sys engineers tell me that it is not suitable for parts of our application; we are using EIGS for those parts and we (apparently) need Lanczos.

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry, we have a misunderstanding probably. When you said "convert to tridiagonal form", I was imagining a change of basis that produced a tridiagonal matrix of the same size $n$ as the original matrix. What Lanczos produces is a tridiagonal matrix of size $m \ll n$ instead. $m$ is of the order of the number of eigenvalues that you need; usually twice that number. You *do* need to apply a dense eigensolver such as QR to this matrix, but it's very fast, done automatically by any package that call itself "Lanczos", and it's typically not an issue at all since it's a small problem.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thanks for clarifying that. I missed the M<<N part.